# Is that possible to paste image to csv or excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

For example I have a script which scrapping data from site and I need to load data into csv. The csv file must contain image ( not url). Is that possible to load images like a file( not url)

P.s : see attachment

I'm tried to work with excel and xlsxwriter library, but had some errors

```
  try:
            for idx,item in enumerate(data_json['items']):
                eng_name = item['product']['release']['name']
                orig_name = item['product']['release']['translated_name']
                img_url = item['product']['release']['image_urls'][0]
                img = Image.open(requests.get(img_url, stream = True).raw)

                img.save(f'{i*idx}.png')
                # with open('test.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                #     f.write(r.content)

                worksheet.set_column('F:F', 30)

                # worksheet.write('F2', 'Insert an image in a cell:')
                worksheet.insert_image(f'F{i*idx}', r"test.png", {'x_scale': 0.1, 'y_scale': 0.1})
                model_num = item['product']['release']['style_code']
                model_num_w_dash = item['product']['release']['style_code'].replace('-', '')
                brand = item['product']['brand']['name']
                id = item['product']['release']['id']
                links = f'https://kream.co.kr/products/{id}' 
                data.append([eng_name,orig_name,model_num,model_num_w_dash,brand,links]) 
        except:
```

Comment: UserWarning: Cannot insert image at (-1, 5).
  warn('Cannot insert image at (%d, %d).' % (row, col))
has except like that

Comment: can you use the bytes `bytearray(img)` or those bytes cast to a hex string?

Comment: For a CSV file the bytes of an (image-)file can be encoded as base64 and written as usual string to the file.

Comment: img = Image.open(requests.get(img_url, stream = True).raw)
so, newImg = bytearray(img) and data.append(newImg) will work?

Comment: I'm saving data using pandas. Is that important?